# Js return true if obj is found with the right attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
let userScopes = [
  {
    scope: 'user',
    actions: ['create', 'read', 'update'],
  },
];

function checked(scope, actions) {
  return !!~userScopes.find(
    _scope =>
      _scope.scope === scope && _scope.actions.lastIndexOf(actions) !== -1
  );
}

console.log(checked("user","create"));//true
console.log(checked("users","create"));//false
console.log(checked("user","creat"));//false
console.log(checked("make","create"));//false
```

I have to make sure if the object the following properties is found then it returns true otherwise false.

But isn't it working, any advice?

Comment: Why do you do a bitwise NOT `~`? A double boolean NOT `!!` is enough for an implicit conversion. A bitwise NOT thrown in is bizarre and will return a completely different value than what you need. Moreover, you can just use `.some` to return a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
function checked(scope, action) {
    return userScopes.some(o => o.scope === scope && o.actions.includes(action));
}

let userScopes = [{ scope: 'user', actions: ['create', 'read', 'update'] }];

console.log(checked("user", "create"));  //  true
console.log(checked("users", "create")); // false
console.log(checked("user", "creat"));   // false
console.log(checked("make", "create"));  // false
```